# How to set the default sort order for answers to be Highest Score?

Tags: bug, sorting

On Stack Overflow, whenever I go on the page for a question, the default sort order is "Date modified (newest first)" instead of "Highest score (default)" which looks like it should be the default since it's mentioned to be the default.

I looked in the settings, but I couldn't find an option to change the default sorting of answers.
Also, this only happens on Stack Overflow, but not on the other communities like [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

So, how can I set the default sorting to be "Highest score (default)"?

**Edit:** I'm adding details to address the questions in the comments.

Here's how I can reproduce it:

- I choose a random question and see it's sorted by "Date modified".
- I click "Reset to default".
- It sorts by "Highest score".
- I choose another random question and it's back to "Date modified".
- I set it to "Highest score" using the drop-down and it sorts by "Highest score".
- I choose another random question and it's back to "Date modified".

So it doesn't remember the last one I chose. It keeps resetting to "Date modified".

The URL doesn't contain `?answertab=modifieddesc` as I choose a question from the homepage.

Comment: Is it not sticking? The system automatically remembers the last sort you used... if you keep switching to highest and it keeps resetting to date modified... then there's a bug but it's unclear whether that's the case from your question... and it works as expected for me. :)

Comment: It is supposed to be saved - are you saying it keeps resetting for you?

Comment: There should be [a "Reset to default" link beside the sorting option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p80UC.png), or you can just change it manually from the drop-down. Otherwise, a possible cause is you (accidentally) accessed a URL ending with `?answertab=modifieddesc` that will automatically change the sorting to "Date modified (newest)"

Comment: I edited my question to answer your questions.

Comment: Weird, I can't repro using the steps you outlined - which browser/version are you using?

Comment: Firefox 100. Weird: I just logged into Chrome and that fixed the issue for other browsers as well.

Comment: might be that the preference is stored server-side as opposed to client-side? I am a bit fuzzy on the details. cc @Catija

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Must be server-side. If I change the sort on my phone, it changes it on my desktop.

Comment: @Catija yeah, server-side. I finally made my lazy *** to go and check: a POST request to the `/questions/<id>` enpoint with `fkey` to identify the user and `sortOrderPreference` with the new preference.

Comment: Is there any updates on this? I'm having the exact same issue as well. It _always_ gets  reset to date modified. (Safari 15.6.1 macOS)

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. Safari 16.0

Comment: I was having this issue, too.  Whenever I clicked the "Reset to default" it would sort the way I wanted, but the next question would always go back to "date modified".  I just tried selecting a few different options directly from the dropdown box and now it seems to be "remembering" what was set in the box from question to question.

Comment: Same problem here. Using Firefox on Windows. Best bet: Upvote the question and give it prominence on the homepage. Someone will take an interest and maybe fix it.